# How does use of HMAC affect hash function combiners?

Tags: hash, hmac

In the comments of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10348/hmac-construction-based-on-the-combination-of-two-hash-functions), Ricky Demer proposes a function $HMAX$ to combine two $HMAC$s based on different hash functions:

$HMAX_{H0,H1}(⟨k_0,k_1⟩,m) = HMAC_{H0}(k_0,m) \oplus HMAC_{H1}(k_1,m)$

The OP also talked about hash function combiners in general and preserving collision-resistance of the underlying hash functions, so I was wondering how the introduction of MAC into a hash function combiner, and this construction specifically, would work.

It appears obvious that this scheme will do a good job of preserving (or even enhancing) the PRF properties of the underlying hash functions (it's quite similar to the TLS PRF combiner, which [Lehman10](http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/id/eprint/2094) showed was 'somewhat robust'), but I'm unclear what it will do to the collision resistance.

The results of [Boneh06](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/hashing.html) and [Pietrzak07](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/348) require the combiner output size to be roughly the concatenated size of both hash functions for CR to be preserved.
On the surface this would appear to rule out the $HMAX$ function above as CR preserving, but I'm not sure whether these proofs extend to covering a keyed construction.

[Mittelbach13](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/210) showed combiners with weaker security guarantees, but shorter output sizes could be produced, as long as it was assumed that one of the hash functions was Indifferentiable from a Random Oracle (IRO) (which also appears to assume a proof in the random oracle model).
Again, I'm not sure whether a) $HMAC$ has an IRO proof, or b) whether the Mittelbach proof covers the use of a keyed construction in the combiner.

I'm also aware that the 'folklore' $\oplus$ combiner does not preserve collision resistance (i.e. it can even create collisions where none existed in the underlying hash functions).
Does this simply (ignoring the use of $HMAC$) apply to this usage, and imply that the combiner cannot preserve CR?

I'm interested in two things:

1. Does the introduction of $HMAC$, or any keyed function in general, complicate/negate the Boneh/Pietrzak/Mittelbach results, or do they apply to any construction?
2. Do any of the results above apply specifically to the $HMAX$ construction described above?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by collision-resistance of a MAC? $\;$

Comment: I'm referring to the collision-resistance of the underlying hash functions - i.e. what happens if you use $HMAC$ as part of a hash function combiner that is intended to be robust wrt collision-resistance (i.e. be collision-resistant if either of the combined hash functions is).

Comment: Would you be assuming that the key is fixed before passing HMAC to the combiner? $\hspace{1.25 in}$

Comment: Hmmm, I imagine the key would have to be fixed by the combiner, otherwise the combiner would not be a (unkeyed) hash function. I wonder if that answers my question.

Comment: I would first look at the series of papers on XOR-MAC (Crypto'95) and its cryptanalysis.

Comment: On indifferentiability of HMAC: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-32009-5_21  Quick summary: if key size is less than block size minus one, indifferentiable; otherwise not, because of possibility of collisions in padded keys.